# Browser History -> Database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to fetch history from browser as soon as a web site is loaded in the browser. It should fetch clients' browser info and save it in a database so that admin may check out the website that is frequently opened and can do survey on the data.

Comment: give your proper tag with question

Comment: What do you mean by "history"? You can get browser specifics in asp.net and activity on your site from IIS, but you can't get the users' activity on other sites.

Comment: i just want d history dat is generated on the browser shud b fetched at the tym my site opens in dat particular browser n save it in sql data base using c#

Answer (score 1):

```
System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities browser = Request.Browser;
string s = "Browser Capabilities\n"
    + "Type = "                    + browser.Type + "\n"
    + "Name = "                    + browser.Browser + "\n"
    + "Version = "                 + browser.Version + "\n"
    + "Major Version = "           + browser.MajorVersion + "\n"
    + "Minor Version = "           + browser.MinorVersion + "\n"
    + "Platform = "                + browser.Platform + "\n"
    + "Is Beta = "                 + browser.Beta + "\n"
    + "Is Crawler = "              + browser.Crawler + "\n"
    + "Is AOL = "                  + browser.AOL + "\n"
    + "Is Win16 = "                + browser.Win16 + "\n"
    + "Is Win32 = "                + browser.Win32 + "\n"
    + "Supports Frames = "         + browser.Frames + "\n"
    + "Supports Tables = "         + browser.Tables + "\n"
    + "Supports Cookies = "        + browser.Cookies + "\n"
    + "Supports VBScript = "       + browser.VBScript + "\n"
    + "Supports JavaScript = "     + 
        browser.EcmaScriptVersion.ToString() + "\n"
    + "Supports Java Applets = "   + browser.JavaApplets + "\n"
    + "Supports ActiveX Controls = " + browser.ActiveXControls 
          + "\n";
```

`Request.Browser` is used to identify the browser info . Using this you can get all info of browser

Answer (score 0):

IIS is already storing this information for you. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525410%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

To make that data useful you will then need to use a Log Analyzer tool.

Google this term for some options to use: iis log analyzer